# Undefines when template loads angular (despite promise)

Tags: javascript, angular

Im loading angular template with data, on load I'm getting errors due to callings undefined properties, after a few seconds downlaoding data from server is finished and template loads with data. So clearly there is asynchronous problem. BUT I have implemented OnInit method to load the needed data to the template, here Im confused and ask fro help.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'drawing',
  templateUrl: './drawing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drawing.component.css']
})

export class DrawingComponent implements OnInit{

  private drawing: Drawing;

  constructor(private drawingService: DrawingService){}

  getDrawing(): void {
     this.drawingService.getDrawing().then((data) => {this.drawing = data});
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDrawing();
  }

getUrl(): string {
    return 'http://www.localhost:8080/api/image/' + this.drawing.drawingUrl;
  }
```

Below Drawing class:

```
export class Drawing {

   drawingId: number;
   drawingUrl: string;
   zoom: number;
   rotation: number;
}
```

below component html tempalte

```
<button (click)="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
<button (click)="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
<button (click)="rotateView()">Rotate</button>
<pdf-viewer
  id="textLayer"
  [src]="getUrl()"
  [page]="page"
  [original-size]="true"
  style="display: block;"
  [zoom]="getZoom()"
  [render-text]="false"
  (click)="getCoordinates($event)"
  [rotation]="getRotation()"
></pdf-viewer>
```

and drawing service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DrawingService {

  private drawingUrl = 'http://www.localhost:8080/api/drawing/1';

  constructor(
    private http: Http){}

  getDrawing(): Promise<Drawing> {
      return this.http.get(this.drawingUrl).toPromise().then((res) => res.json() as Drawing);
  }

}
```

So First on load Im getting

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawingUrl' of undefined
    at DrawingComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/drawing/drawing.component.ts.DrawingComponent.getUrl
```

and after few seconds it loads

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about how Promises work. You are obviously trying to access the `drawing` member before its ready. Your `getUrl` method is the likely culprit.

Comment: A Promise is simply a convenient way of doing B as soon as A finishes at some arbitrary point in the future. Since you are trying to access the result of B before A finishes, you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I'm most likely due to the fact that `promise` will take as long as it need before returning data to the component. So by then your component have already loaded. Try checking if the values are present on the HTML file with `*ngIf` before populating the variable. Then it will appear when it's ready and you shouldn't see the error of `undefined`

Comment: I thought html template won't be rendered until ngOnInit finishes.

Comment: `ngOnInit` *does* finish, but the http request triggered by it doesn't until a few seconds after. You mentioned "asynchronous" in your question, yet you seem unaware of the implications.

Comment: Have a look at the Async part of this doc. You'll understand why there is a delay. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#async-services-and-promises